# Android studio new button activity not starting shows : Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, xml

Please help me i am facing problem in starting an new button activity in android studio. It shows **null pointer exception** and **exception in plugin android support**. what should i do ?

[image: show the screenshot]

I also added my java and xml main activity coding please review it.

My Xml main activity coding...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context="comhanumanbeniwaloffice.facebook.www.hanumanbeniwal.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:text="परिचय"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="Latest News"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
        android:text="ब्लॉग"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="तस्वीरें"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="विडियो"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="लाइव"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPressedHighlight"
        android:text="Speech"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="Contact"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button2"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java Main activity coding...

```js
package comhanumanbeniwaloffice.facebook.www.hanumanbeniwal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.NewAndroidComponentAction.actionPerformed(NewAndroidComponentAction.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:197)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:211)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:905)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$300(TransactionGuardImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:109)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:112)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: you normally need to post the code... without that is hard to help anyone

Comment: i have added java and xml main activity coding please review it.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace ??

Comment: how to check stacktrace ?